# File Organization for express project

Tags: node.js, express, file-organization

I am making a node website using express.  I now have a lot of files in my project and was wondering on how to organize them.  The root project directory is organized like any standard express project

```
proj _nodemodules
    |_public
    |_view
    |_routes
    |...
```

Right now, all my route files are packed into the route directory and all my view files are packed into the view directory.  When I attempted to sort out my views and routes into sub-directories it gets very tedious, for example in many of my view files I have to change `extend layout` to `extend ../layout`.  I also have to make similar changes to many of my route files.  So my question is if this is necessary/good practice to organize my express project with sub-directories

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to have subdirectories and categorize your views/routes as it will lead to low maintenance costs as you can get to the file faster as well as if you developing another module or enhancing existing one this can lead to reusability of the code leading to less code.
You never know that when you start refactoring and putting the code into the appropriate place thsn you might lead to deleting duplicate/redundant code